# Why does TinyMce add empty divs to the body of the page

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

I have a form with multiple narratives and while using this library and I noticed that there were some empty html elements being added to the body of the page

- Why does TinyMce add empty divs to the body of the page ?

- Why is it that the toolbar div is not removed when we step out of the component  ?

[image showing 'Elements'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipA1c.png)

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/inline-demo/